# What's a good hyptothesis testing method of non-gaussian distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, chi-squared-test

Let's say I have a single set of measurements, $M$ comprised of $N=10^4$ values (or so, I can increase if neccessary). The distribution of values are not gaussian.

What I want is to gather $N' < N$ new samples and determine whether or not it matches the distribution of $M$ or not (the null hypothesis). The new samples are generated on-the-fly so as soon as I have enough to decide with a confidence of level of 0.95 (or so) I will abort.

I've been looking at Student's t-test but it looks like it only works with normal distributions (or have I misunderstood?). Chi-squared looks promising but I'm unsure how to divide my data into categories, should I use bins like a histogram?

**Alternative**:
An alternative way is too look at the problem like a binary classification problem, if that would give better results? This could work since the samples can actually only be part of two (very similar) distributions $M$ and $M'$, there are no other possibilities.

**Background:**
What I have right now is a simple comparison of means, which works but require a pretty large sample-size, also I don't know what level of confidence I'm getting. I'm seeking to reduce the sample size ($N'$), but the size of $N$ does not matter since $M$ it can be reused.

Comment: Can you clarify "What I want is to gather ′< new samples" where it seems to be a number of sample, while we had the feeling that N was the sample size of M "  comprised of =104 values"?

Comment: I have $N$ samples in $M$ ($N=|M|$). But now I want to test another number $N'$ of samples and test if they are from the same distribution as $M$. I'm not sure if I'm clear. I want $N'$ to be as small as possible, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test if you are sure about non-normality of your data. It is a non-parametric test and tests whether the sample median is different than the hypothesized median.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).